# Unity 2017.3: Preview script created UI elements in editor

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have a canvas with attached script that creates an UI programmatically. What I would like to achieve is to be able to see the UI in editor. I've tried to mark this class as `[ExecuteInEditMode]` but the problem with that is that the `Awake` method where I create the UI is called every time I enter play mode, therefore creating new and new copies of the UI elements and never deleting them.

Here is a sample code I'm using:

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class InGameCanvas : MonoBehaviour {
    protected InGameCanvas() { }

    private Canvas canvas;

    private void Awake() {
        if ((canvas = gameObject.GetComponent<Canvas>()) == null) {
            Debug.LogError("InGameCanvas script not connected to a Canvas.");
            return;
        } 

        var balanceTextObject = new GameObject("BalanceText");
        balanceTextObject.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform);
        var balanceText = balanceTextObject.AddComponent<Text>();
        var balanceTextTransform = balanceTextObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>();

        balanceText.text = "Balance: 0";
        balanceText.font = Defaults.consolasFont;

        balanceTextTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(100, 20);
        balanceTextTransform.pivot = new Vector2(0, 1);
        balanceTextTransform.anchorMin = new Vector2(0, 1);
        balanceTextTransform.anchorMax = new Vector2(0, 1);

        balanceTextTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(10, -10);
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to also preview some other objects created by scripts as they will be on play mode run, but I'm having same problem. `[ExecuteInGameMode]` also says, it will run other code of the script as well, which I don't really need. All I need is to run the `Awake` function in editor to preview the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Awake () {
    if (!Application.isPlaying) {
        // Your Code Here.
    }
}
```

EDIT: Or

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    // Your Code Here.
#endif
```

This executes the block only when Unity is in "Editor" mode and not "Playing".

Comment: You haven't written a simple word to explain or why should your solution be correct

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Also if I understand it right, what you are suggesting, this solves nothing at all. It will show in editor, but then when application starts in real product, it will skip the creation code.

Comment: And also it is creating copies after i exit play mode.

Comment: I changed the answer. :)

Comment: Again doesn't solve my issue but it gave me an idea on how to do this.

Comment: Okay, sorry for the mess. I've only just started using SO again. ^^